# How do I insert array results as an array parameter of a function?

Tags: php

I am looping a PHP array, and I get as results:

```
david
darwin
sara
```

I want to call a function with these results as array parameter. It must be like this:

```
$det = $obj->getDetails(array(
    'david',
    'darwin',
    'sara',
));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? if you provide that information, someone may be able to correct your errors.

Comment: Which is your original array? And which array you want to send as a parameter?

Comment: Looks like question is not well formatted, and insufficient information

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1:

```
<?php
    // If you have a string.
    $string = 'david darwin sara';
    $array = explode(' ', $string);
    $det= $obj->getDetails($array);
```

Array output: https://eval.in/1000612

Answer 2:

```
<?php
    // If you have an array at the beginning and let's say
    // your array is like this.
    $users = array(
      array('name' => 'david', 'age' => 35, 'something' => ....),
      array('name' => 'darwin', 'age' => 30, 'something' => ....),
      array('name' => 'sara', 'age' => 45, 'something' => ....)
    );

    $array = [];
    foreach($users as $item){
        $array[] = $item['name'];
    }

    $det = $obj->getDetails($array);
```

Array output: https://eval.in/1000614

Comment: only issue is that its adding  [0] => at the first element of array

Comment: this is output now (first answer) [0] => 'david',
'darwin',
'sata',

Comment: Please check the outputs, the array keys always will be there. So 0:"david", 1:"darwin", 2:"sara"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like the following:

```html
$det = array();
foreach ($results as $key => $name) {
  $det[$key] = $obj->getDetails($name);
}
```

Comment: no my friend we must call the function only one time , in your example we will call the function every time that there is a value in $results variable